# Can I use iChat with MSN through its new XMPP/Jabber compatibility?

Tags: ichat, jabber, xmpp

The Windows Team blog [announced](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/12/14/anyone-can-build-a-windows-live-messenger-client-with-open-standards-access-via-xmpp.aspx) XMPP compatibility with their MSN/Live IM network recently.

Have anyone tried to get iChat to work with MSN yet? 
(I'm not looking for Jabber transports)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not implemented yet.

In the meanwhile, you can use [Cocoon](http://cocoon.drinkbrainjuice.com/) for MSN chat as an iChat extension.

Comment: This answer got a bit outdated I think. No updates (or anything) from Cocoon for a year.

Comment: @Alenanno Did it stop working?

Comment: @Gerry I haven't even installed it, considering the project seems to be dead and seems it has been for a year. Not to mention it still had problems (failure to load avatars, no chance to add, block or remove contacts and so on).

Answer (score 0):

As Gerry said, Cocoon is your only option at the moment - but it hasn't been touched in months, despite continued donations from users.

Comment: ^ should be a commment really.